# 1 MHz clock on a perfboard

Tags: noise, high-frequency, board

I'm doing a prototype on a perfboard and I need to use a square wave of 1 MHz at least. The square wave is for a clock pulse and I generate it with a AC generator.

I want to know if at that frequency  I will have some electromagnetics problems and if there is a way to minimize them.

I add the part of the circuit where I need to emit the 1 MHz pulse. The part where it goes to the FF, it is a counter.

[image]

Comment: The capacitance between tracks can be obtained from the datasheet.

Comment: This is too vague to really answer.  You can do 1 MHz on perfboard for sure, but it depends on your circuit, your construction technique, and what performance you require.  Even if you provide that detail, the answer is probably going to be "build it and see if it works"

Comment: 1 MHz is still a relatively low frequency.  Keep your connections as short as possible is the number 1 rule.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers! I added the circuit to clarify what I need to do.

Comment: i've done 20Mhz clocks with breadboard and jumper wires (5cm), so you'll be fine if it's kept on the board and nothing else weird is going on.

Comment: It should work. You can also use ground plane perfboard like in this picture: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/CopperCladPerfboard_2.png/220px-CopperCladPerfboard_2.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done 70 plus MHz on perfboards. So the answer is unlikely (that you will have an electromagnetics problem). But it is dependent on what you are doing and however you are doing it.

Comment: Do you have some rules of thumb to avoid screwing it up?

Comment: 1) Make the circuit as compact as possible. If you have 20 IC's, don't string them out in a line, but make a 4 x 5 grid. 2) Connect your grounds in a grid, not a daisy-chain. 3) Use fairly thick conductors for your ground - not skinny wires. 4) Use a decoupling capacitor (ceramic) at each IC, with leads connected to the ICs as close as possible. Under no circumstances should lead length be more than an inch. 5) Your power connections should also form a grid similar to ground, but as long as you have good decoupling it doesn't need to be quite as robust as the ground grid.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to connect the ground in a grid? Or it's just do a grid of wires and put the ground there?

Answer (score 1):

I built a 70-SSI/MSI video game on perfboard, with DIPs in sockets. Each DIP socket had pin7-14 or pin8-16 bypass cap (0.1uF?).

And a ground grid, built by hand, with thick solid-conductor-wire running in X and in Y, soldered at every socket. The clockrate was 10 Hertz, but the edges were fast so as to prevent data rushing thru the cascade of flipflops become some FFs might otherwise clock 50 or 100nS later because of SLOW Clock rise time.

Comment: The video game worked, first pass. But I'd served as a test technician on digital PCBs, and was bluntly faced with the wide traces in X for GND and wide traces in Y for VDD, with 0.01uF leaded caps at each "Utilogic" (4.5 volt logic from Signetics) IC. With that example (actually dozens of PCBs of various sorts), I was nervous about NOT HAVING A GROUND GRID and have included on all projects since.